# Matching generator/iterator in jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

Is there a way in jest to match output of a generator?

Like this:

```js
function *f() {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}

it('', () => {
  expect(f()).toMatchObject([ 1, 2, 3 ])
})
```

And like this:

```js
class X {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  }
}

it('', () => {
  expect(new X).toMatchObject([ 1, 2, 3 ])
})
```

And like this too:

```js
class X {
  get y() {
    return new Y
  }
}
class Y {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
  }
}

it('', () => {
  expect(new X).toMatchObject({ y : [ 1, 2, 3 ] })
})
```

It would be wonderful if approach can handle multiple nested *iterable* objects within single `expect` call.

Comment: Shouldn't `function f()` be `function *f()`?

Comment: Yes, You are right!